# Mongoose: Set default value in a required field when this is not present in the document to save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to set a default value in an empty field for a document to be saved in the MongoDB

In my case, this is the mongoose schema

```
var Distribution = new Schema({
    temporalCoverage: {
        startDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        endDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    },
    distributionText: String
});
```

This is the document to save:

```
"distribution": {
    "temporalCoverage": {
      "endDate": "",
      "startDate": ""
    },
    "distributionText": "test"
  }
```

In this document, the empty fields are endDate and startDate. The document is saved in mongoDB with null values.

```
"distribution": {
    "temporalCoverage": {
      "endDate": null,
      "startDate": null
    },
    "distributionText": "test"
  }
```

I want to save the default value, not null

If a put the field required in the schema, `temporalCoverage : { startDate : { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }, endDate : { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now } }`I get the error validation, and the document is no saved it.

Comment: Try not providing these keys when updating. Do not set them as wmpty strings.

Answer (score 11):

You need the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option

```
var schema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  genre: {type: String, default: 'Action'}
});

var Movie = db.model('Movie', schema);

var query = {};
var update = {title: 'The Terminator'};
var options = {
  // Create a document if one isn't found. Required
  // for `setDefaultsOnInsert`
  upsert: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true
};

Movie.
  findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (error, doc) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    assert.equal(doc.title, 'The Terminator');
    assert.equal(doc.genre, 'Action');
  });
```

see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html

Comment: The `new` option is not a valid option for the Mongoose `update()` operation and is not needed. Setting the `upsert`option to `true` is enough to guarantee that Mongoose will create a new document if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`, which should be working.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?